# Create user with email and password using angular 5 firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular5

I would like to create one user with email and password more another data, for example name
In my interface I have this:

```
export interface UserInterface {

  id?: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  status: string

 constructor(auth) {
   this.id = auth.uid
 }
}
```

and my service I have:

```
createUser(user: UserInterface) {
  return this.angularFireAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
}
```

How I can add atributes name and uid in ID ?

Comment: No you can't add more data along with this method! The UID and security is taken care by the firebase

Comment: You're supposed to put additional data in the database, not in the auth system. When the user signs up, create the auth user and get the new uid, then write additional fields to the db under whatever path you want, something like `/user_profiles/{uid}`.

Comment: so, I don't want to put data in auth system, I want assossiation auth system with database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RESOLVED] To me, I did this way

AuthService I have

```
  createUser(user: UserInterface) {
       return this.angularFireAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
                            .then(() => {
                              this.service.save(user);
                            })
                            .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  }
```

And in my UserService I have

```
save(user: any) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if(user.key) {
    this.db.list(this.PATH)
          .update(user.key, ({ name: user.name }))
          .then(() => resolve())
          .catch((e) => reject(e))
  } else {
    this.db.list(this.PATH)
            .push({ name: user.name })
            .then(() => resolve())
    }
  })
}
```

This way, I can create a User using Email and Password in Auth system and I add atributers to this User in UserService, this way I done!